# Rails console does not recognize new class name after a rename_table migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I wrote a migration to change one of the table name.

```
class RenameFooToBar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :foos, :bars
  end
end
```

After `db:migration` and a `reload!` in `rails console` I was expecting to be able to use the class `Bar` to refer to the renamed table i.e. `Bar.create(name: 'bar1')`. But it gives me a NameError, so what did I missed or how do I setup this relation manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming table is not enough, you need to rename `app/models/foo.rb` to `app/models/bar.rb` and also change the class name inside this file from `class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base` to `class Bar < ActiveRecordBase`. Also scan for any usage of constant `Foo`.